# Java when Instantiating 2 new objects any change to the first is applied to the second

Tags: java, jpa, zk

I have a Booking object that contains two Places objects in that way :

```
@Entity @Table(name = "booking", schema = "public")
public class Booking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pickup_place_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Place pickUpPlace;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dropoff_place_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Place dropOffPlace;
}
```

For the Place Object :

```
@Entity @Table(name = "place", schema = "public")
public class Place {

    public enum PlaceType{
        PICKUP,
        STOP,
        DROPOFF,
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "place_type", nullable = false)
    private Place.PlaceType placeType;

    @Column(name = "google_place_id", nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String googlePlaceId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private City city;

    @Column(name = "lat", nullable = true)
    private Double lat;

    @Column(name = "lon", nullable = true)
    private Double lon;
}
```

then in a controller when populating a new booking I instantiate the places like this :

```
Booking booking = new Booking();
booking.setPickUpPlace(new Place(city, googlePlaceId , Place.PlaceType.PICKUP));
booking.setDropOffPlace(new Place(city, googlePlaceId , Place.PlaceType.DROPOFF));
```

at a later stage in the controller I happen to update the booking PickUp Place city with :

```
booking.getPickUpPlace().setCity(otherCity);
```

and the result was that both the pickupPlace and the dropOffPlace of the booking end up with the otherCity asigned to them.

Then I started to add logs at several stages in the controller and when logging the objects pickUpPlace and dropOffPlace just after instantiating I got the same result :

```
com.myapp.domain.Place@2af
com.myapp.domain.Place@2af
```

The same object hash code, which seemed to be normal to me because the objects were not yet persisted to DB yet and therefore without id, and the default HashCode only uses the id and the version number of the saved object...

Just to be sure the issue was not there I overrode the HashCode (){} and equals(){} of the Place Object with a more complete hash and equal taking into account all the properties of the object... and here, magic, the issue disappeared and the 2 instantiated objects are correctly differentiated and a change in one is not done in the other one anymore.

So my issue is solved. Only By luck I would say as the 2 instantiated Place happen to have the PlaceType with a a different value, but what if I had to instantiate 2 objects with same initial values ? (which will happen when I will start to add PlaceType.STOPS to the booking... those will be instantiated with the same initial values)

I don't like to solve an issue without understanding where the problem really was...
Does this mean that in Java when instantiating 2 objects, not yet persisted, with the same properties they in fact point to the same object in memory ? Or is there an architectural problem in my project ?

Thanks in advance to Java Experts for a quick explaination of the observed phenomena for a Java noob...

Comment: `new` is __guaranteed__ to make a new object. Your theory (that 2 instantiated Place objects are automatically compressed down to a single ref) is not correct. I'm not sure there's enough detail in this to know what happened. Possibly something as simple as 'you forgot to compile before you reran that code'.

Comment: Thanks  rzwitserloot,  unfortunately the issue is not so simple, if I remove the overiding hash and equal in the Place object the issue comes back. thanks anyway for clarifying the fact that the 2 objects instanciated with NEW must be different, I will keep searching for the problem elsewhere then, but i will not leave this "Dirty solution" untill i get why this happens... will post more complete objets and controllers if I am stuck too long. Controler is a ZK MVVM view model, so i will investigate there also...

Comment: ok, reason found, this is a ZK dataBinding issue, I replaced the '''@Bind''' by a '''@load''' on the html (zul) to manually control the update of the Place.City with a OnChange event of the control and it works without having to override the hash and equals in the Domain... Thanks for putting on right track, I was loosing time searching for the issue with java